# Optional non-positional arguments Python program

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python code to be run from the command line in bash. It receives the following arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a')
parser.add_argument('b')
parser.add_argument('c', nargs='?', default=None)
parser.add_argument('d', nargs='?', default=None)
parser.add_argument('e', nargs='?', default=None)

arg_parser = create_arg_parser()
parsed_args, unknown = arg_parser.parse_known_args()
print(parsed_args)
```

*a* and *b* are the only mandatory arguments. I want *c*, *d* and *e* to be optional, so if the user does not specify them, the program can run anyway.

In the previous code, I am printing the arguments because I am having issues specifying them.

If I run my program like this:

```
python myScript.py a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
```

it works perfectly! The output is:

```
a='a1', b='b1', c='c1', d='d1', e='e1'
```

If I do this (I omitted the argument 'e'):

```
python myScript.py a1 b1 c1 d1
```

The output is fine again (I expect 'e' to be None):

```
a='a1', b='b1', c='c1', d='d1', e=None
```

But, the problem comes when I do this:

```
python myScript.py a1 b1 d1
```

As the output is:

```
a='a1', b='b1', c='d1', d=None, e=None
```

I do not want d1 related to c, but with d. I do not get to tell the program to take ANY order in the optional arguments provided. Do you have any ideas to solve this?

Comment: no, because it cannot be solved without guessing which arguments were skipped.

Comment: I have hunch, but a question first. Do your arguments have some specific values they can take on ? If yes, then you could check that for example you assign to c only those values which are allowed for argument c, and same for the other arguments. This way you can eliminate incorrect assignments without needing specific order of arguments.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop not really. Values for c, d and e can be "infinite". I cannot extract all the possible values for those arguments. How else can I solve this?

Comment: Any reason you don't use the optional args with dashes? `parser.add_argument('-c', nargs='?', default=None)`, then you can do  `python myScript.py a b -d d1
`

Comment: @schwobaseggl I had no idea I could do this. Seems a very good idea. Let me try!

Comment: @schwobaseggl it worked! Thank you very much! For me, this is the answer

Comment: You probably don't need `nargs='?'` for the optionals.  The default `nargs` value is just fine.

Comment: The arguments that you defined are recognized by position only.  `python myscript.py 1 2 3`.  Can a user, much less the program, tell that the 3 was meant for `d` or `e` as opposed to `c`?

Answer (score 0):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a')
parser.add_argument('b')
parser.add_argument('-c')
parser.add_argument('-d')
parser.add_argument('-e')

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
print(parsed_args)
```

use with

```
python myScript.py a1 b1 -c c1 -d d1
python myScript.py a1 -d d1 b1
etc
```